# Porting of Android app to windows phone 8 onwards

Tags: android, windows-phone-8

I have an android app already developed. But now I need to port my app onto windows 8 phone.
I have Linux socket, pthread , timers and other system Apis in my app. Can I use any library which can translate these Apis to windows Apis.If yes then how can I do this and which library should I use for that? or whether i have to replace all this APIs with windows API?

Comment: Have you tried searching anything ? Maybe something like that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741621%28VS.85%29.aspx for example. But here it seems like you're just asking us to do the job for you

Comment: Eh, Windows uses C++ while Android uses Java. You have to start from scratch. It's the same as trying to port from Android to iOS. Not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an artical on how you can port your andriod app to windows phone 8 app. this might help you to port your app to windows phone. But there is not any porting tool convert your app code in windows phone. also study some metrial on msdn on windows phone 8 as there are alot of features which are not available windows phone.

[Transforming an Android App into a Windows Phone App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh965662.aspx)

Comment: P:S I will recomend to use windows 8.1 Universal app while converting your andriod app. because you can share common code for windows phone app and widows 8.1 app.